# 'ToastNotifier' object has no attribute 'classAtom'

Tags: python

I ran the code below;

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Hello World!!!",
                   "Python is 10 seconds awsm!",
                   icon_path="custom.ico",
                   duration=10)
```

I am getting below error :

```
  File "C:\Users\jnp\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win10toast\__init__.py", line 83, in _show_toast
self.hwnd = CreateWindow(self.classAtom, "Taskbar", style,

AttributeError: 'ToastNotifier' object has no attribute 'classAtom'
```

Comment: i just ran it and i got the notification

Comment: looks like there's some version mismatch or it is dependent on other modules

Comment: Oh dear... The [spot in the code where classAtom is assigned](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/blob/master/win10toast/__init__.py#L78) is wrapped in a `try: ... except: pass` block, which is generally considered a no-no. Since it's suppressing all diagnostic error information, all we know is that _something_ went wrong during the RegisterClass call. If you're feeling intrepid, maybe you could edit the library's code to include some logging.

Comment: @Kevin, and the funny thing is they mentioned..they are not sure of this..instead of printing the actual exception

Comment: This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/issues/33) going back to April.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with the source code itself. [image: Code Screenshot here]

if you see the image, if there is an exception happening at `self.classAtom = RegisterClass(self.wc)` they did not handle it which will leave `classAtom` variable not declared. That is the cause of your problem. So, to fix it, just make `classAtom = ""` or some thing. But, this wont actually fix it.

Answer (score 6):

What was causing this for me was creating multiple instances of ToastNotifier(). Reusing the same instance fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @InAFlash, The classAtom is returning nothing and the reason is because there is already a registered notification. Messing with the source, I added an exception print to the except block as below:

```
try:
    self.classAtom = RegisterClass(self.wc)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I am running my notifications in threads and when the code comes across this point it prints out the below error:

```
(1410, 'RegisterClass', 'Class already exists.')
```

Looking through it I think I found a solution, though it kind of takes away from the idea of "spamming" the notifications. By adding to the `self.wc.lpszClassName` variable the `title`, it makes it a different notification. So overall the code should look something like this:

```
self.wc = WNDCLASS()
self.hinst = self.wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
self.wc.lpszClassName = str(f"PythonTaskbar{title}")  # must be a string
self.wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map  # could also specify a wndproc.
try:
    self.classAtom = RegisterClass(self.wc)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This solution worked for my scenario so not sure if this is the best fix but I'm rolling with it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the accepted answer might break more things down the line, I'll post this.

It is, as `inAFlash` mentioned in his comment, a dependency issue. Updating `setuptools` will fix the problem.

To do so, simply run: `python -m pip install setuptools --upgrade`