# AttributeError: 'ToastNotifier' object has no attribute 'classAtom'

Tags: python, tkinter, toast

I'm working with tkinter and win10toast. I want it to send notifications when I click the button in tkinter. The notifications do work when I click the button but I get the error below: AttributeError: 'ToastNotifier' object has no attribute 'classAtom'

I hope someone can help me out here! thanks in advance!

My tkinter code looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import notif2

window = tk.Tk()

def noti():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        notif2.main()
        window.after(1000, noti)
        
Button(text='press',command=noti).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

and my notifications code looks like this:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
import time

def main():
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast("Hello World!!!",
    "Python is 10 seconds awsm!",
    icon_path=None,
    duration=1,
    threaded=True)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['ToastNotifier' object has no attribute 'classAtom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741455/toastnotifier-object-has-no-attribute-classatom)

Comment: Nope but I found it out myself! It's because I filled in an interval = 1milliseconds. It works fine above like 1200 milliseconds

Comment: @Jellevs: Maybe you should consider posting this as an answer to your question (yes, it's okay to answer your own question), so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: @Atlas435 Ok when running multiple notifiers I again get the error message. Looking at the thread you send I don't really understand what they mean. Could you maybe explain what I have to do to fix it?

Comment: Try creating only one instance of `ToastNotifier` outside `main()` in `notif2.py`.  I wonder why you called `window.after(...)` inside `noti()`.

Comment: @Jellevs like in the provided link explained. Either use just one instance of notifier or you have to edit the source code of win10toast which I wouldn't recommend to.

Comment: In general the Notifier should be bound to the root window, since the root will be alive and accessible for all other windows as long as the application is running. Why do you think you need two or more instances and why do you think you need the notifier at all?

Comment: Some of you adviced me to use only one instance of notifier. However I'm trying to make 2 or more different notifications with different intervals. This can't be done in one instance right? Or how should I tackle that?